# Move files S3 to Ftb using bash script

Tags: bash, amazon-s3

I want to move files from Amazon s3 to ftp using bash script command...

I already tried

```
rsync --progress -avz -e ssh s3://folder//s3://folder/
```

Can anyone please suggest the correct command?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

AWS built sync in their cli,

> aws s3 sync ./localdir s3://mybucket

You can sync your local directory to remote bucket.

How to install aws cli?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html

If you don't want to take the cli installation route, you can use docker to connect to a container, share your local directory to that container and perform the sync.

https://hub.docker.com/r/mesosphere/aws-cli/

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion...can u please give me a  for ftb one folder to another folder using bash command???   using server path with username and password!!!

Comment: `aws ftp sync ftp://example.com:password@ftp://folder name/ ftp://example.com/folder2/` i tried but got error..."no such a files or directory"

Answer (score 0):

You can't copy objects from S3 in that way because S3 is not an SSH service, it a file storage. So the easiest way is to mount the S3 bucket. Then you can use it like a normal volume and copy all files to the target. 
You should do that on the target system otherwise you have to copy all the file over the third server or computer.

https://www.interserver.net/tips/kb/mount-s3-bucket-centos-ubuntu-using-s3fs/

Comment: can u please give me a move ftb one folder to another folder using bash command??? using server path with username and password!!